# How to use Jquery UI Datetimepicker Widget in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui, ionic2

i am doing an app with Ionic 2 Angular 2 and Typescript and i need a datepicker that has the capability of making some dates unselectable, like only let fridays selectable. 
i looked over the internet for all possible modules or plugins but couldn't find one. 
The jquery UI widget is not made for ionic 2 but i am willing to integrate it but the problem is that i couldn't do it, i installed Jquery and Jquery UI through npm imported them into my .ts file but yet i can't run this since it says

```
Property 'datepicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

This is the code i am trying to run, as you can see i am waiting for the view to load and then running this :

**TS**

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CircuitReservationModal');
    $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input item-right type="text" id="datepicker">
```

So what am i missing ? and if there is any other solutions instead of this Jquery Ui widget i would like to try it!

Thanks